# How can I judge my html is loaded by mobile phone's browser or app's webView, or pc browser?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a html5 page, it can be loaded by mobile phone's browser, pc browser, and my app's webView, in there how can I judge my html page is loaded by which of the upper three different situations?

---

**EDIT**

I mainly want to know if the html is loaded by my app's webView.

The html has a button, which can provide a method, but can access the database, if I use my app's webView to load the html, I will pass the user-id to the method, because there is no cookie here, if I loaded the html by mobile phone's browser and pc's browser, there is cookie for saving the user-id, I will not pass user-id to the html.

Comment: What actually you want to do..?

Comment: Use navigator.userAgent, the userAgents of mobile phone, pc browser and app's WebView are different

Comment: @RïshïKêshKümar I updated my post.

Comment: Your app has full control over the resources it loads in a webview, it can inject whatever you want into the loaded page so the page local code knows it's running in the webview.

Comment: @pvg, but if the pc browser load the webview, I will not inject my user-id, because there have the cookie.

Comment: You were asking how you can tell your page is loaded into your app vs something else. Your app can tell your page it's loaded into your app.